# Can someone please check this piece of writing?

Tags: simplified-characters, writing, learning, writing-critique, mistakes

I don't know if this is the right place to ask for a correction, but I will try. Can someone please check this piece of writing and tell me if there are any mistakes? Thank you so much for the help.

我的城市

我出生在里米尼。因为我在这里住了二十年了,所以我是一个里米尼通。
在我的城市中心有几个很有名的教堂和博物馆。每年有很多游客从世界各地来里米尼游览古迹。
里米尼人也很喜欢去中心买东西,散步,见朋友。在里米尼有很多有意思的地方。凯沃尔广场是一个特别精美的地方。在这儿有一个大喷泉和一个真漂亮雕塑。广场对面还有许多非常好的餐厅和酒吧。"日餐厅"做饭做得很好吃,它是我最喜欢的餐厅。
里米尼是一个海边城市, 所以夏天我跟我的男朋友一起去海滩。附近有一家多厅电影院。我很喜欢去这里看电影。
我爱我的城市。

Comment: suggestion:1st sentence: instead of 在 use 于：cf.
费德里柯·费里尼出生于意大利的里米尼市，德里奥·罗西：出生于意大利东部海滨城市里米尼 2nd,3rd,6th sentences: omit 在

Comment: There are few minor improvements but any Chinese won't have problem to understand this. If you write this yourself, well done.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we aren't here to provide a proofreading service, and the OP has not stated any _specific_ questions about their text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty fine, just to make it more natural:

我的城市

我出生在里米尼。<del>因为</del>我在这里住了二十年了,所以我是一个里米尼通。 在我的城市中心有几个很有名的教堂和博物馆。每年有很多游客从世界各地来里米尼游览古迹。 里米尼人也很喜欢去**市**中心买东西,散步,见朋友。在里米尼有很多有意思的地方。凯沃尔广场是一个特别精美的地方<s>。</s>**，**在<s>这</s>**那**儿有一个大喷泉和一个<s>真</s>**特别**漂亮**的**雕塑。广场对面还有许多非常好的餐厅和酒吧。"日餐厅"做饭做得很好吃,它是我最喜欢的餐厅。 里米尼是一个海边城市, 所以夏天我跟我的男朋友一起去海滩。附近有一家多厅电影院<s>。</s>**，**我很喜欢去<s>这</s>**那**里看电影。 我爱我的城市。